# WordPress get taxonomy title/name

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I've been searching for a way to get and output a custom-type-post title/taxonomy rather than hard-coding the title.

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'portfolio'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'portfolio');
register_post_type('portfolio', // Register Custom Post Type
    array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Portfolio', 'html5blank'), // Rename these to suit
```

What I have on my template but it breaks the column, if I put the h1 outside/above the query_post then "Portfolio" title won't output.

```
<section id="portfolio">
        <div class="row">
        <!-- <h3>Portfolio</h3> -->

            <?php
              query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio' ) );
              if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            ?>
<h1><?php post_type_archive_title(); ?></h1>
                <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns">
                    <?php echo the_content(); ?>
                    <!-- <br class="clear"> -->
                    <h3>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h3>
                    <br class="clear">

                    <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image]

So I'm trying to output "portfolio" to my template I tried this but I'm confused how to get the registered name.

```
<?php
 $terms = get_terms('my-taxonomy-name');
 foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 echo $term->slug.' ';
 }
?>
```

Edit:

```
<?php
                global $wp_post_types;
                $obj = $wp_post_types['portfolio'];
                echo "<h3>";
                    echo $obj->labels->name;
                echo "</h3>";
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [`get_post_type_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object) function:

```
$obj = get_post_type_object( 'portfolio' );
echo $obj->labels->name;
```

to get the registered labels for the `portfolio` custom post type.

Comment: doesn't work, however I put global as well then it did work :/

Comment: What did you put global? ps: you shouldn't use `query_posts()` as explained in the Codex.

Comment: see my edit, I used query_post to output the custom-post-type though.

Comment: Strange, since this global setup should be the same as    `get_post_type_object()` as [stated in the Codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object#Examples). Here's the [note from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) regarding `query_posts()`: *This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. ...  is overly simplistic and problematic ... Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods ...*

Comment: so how else could you output custom-post-type? Yeah I know it was strange though :/. Edit "I think I know how to output custom-post-type" but if you have other ways then that'd be great.

Comment: You should be able to use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` instead of `query_posts` or the `pre_get_posts` action. You also don't need `echo` when you use `the_content()`.